# MERN App: Error with require("dotenv").config()

Tags: reactjs, mern, dotenv

Working on a MERN app and after requiring dotenv I am getting errors with: can't resolve "os" and can't resolve "crypto" I am trying to figure out the solution as I have install dotenv and ran npm install --save path-browserify os-browserify crypto-browserify multiple times. They all appear in my package.json. Any solutions would be appreciated so that I can securely deploy!

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling dependancies, starting fresh from a new react app, adding in a polyfills.js file and importing.  The app compiles fine without dotenv. It cannot find the process variable.

Comment: Hello! Can you please be more specific as to which action you're performing that's resulting in the errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.